# Dapper brings null values

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de hacer que Dapper devuelva una consulta de muchos a muchos donde el "Empleado" tiene múltiples "Rubros". El problema es que no me trae los valores de la columna "nombre_rubro" del elemento "Rubro".
Aquí está el código:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<List<Empleado>>> Get()
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT r.descripcion,r.nombre_rubro, e.*, rxe.id_rubro FROM Rubro r INNER JOIN RubroXEmpleado rxe ON  r.id_rubro = rxe.id_rubro INNER JOIN Empleado e ON  rxe.id_empleado = e.id_empleado ";
        var empleados = await db.QueryAsync<Empleado, Rubro, Empleado>(sql, (empleado, rubro) => {
            empleado.rubros.Add(rubro);                
            return empleado;
        }, splitOn: "id_rubro");
        var result = empleados.GroupBy(p => p.id_empleado).Select(g =>
        {
            var groupedPost = g.First();
            groupedPost.rubros = g.Select(p => p.rubros.Single()).ToList();
            return groupedPost;
        });
        return result.ToList();
     

    }
```

La entidad Empleado:

```
public class Empleado
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int id_empleado { get; set; }
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }
    public int activo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int preferencia_cobro { get; set; }
    public List<Rubro> rubros { get; set; }
    public Empleado()
    {
        this.rubros = new List<Rubro>();
    }
}
```

La entidad Rubro:

```
 public class Rubro
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int id_rubro { get; set; }
    public string nombre_rubro { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }


}
```

Los tipos de atributos son los mismos que en la BD.

El JSON que estoy recibiendo:

```
    [{
    "id_empleado": 2,
    "id_usuario": 1020,
    "activo": 1,
    "descripcion": "",
    "preferencia_cobro": 0,
    "rubros": [
      {
        "id_rubro": 1,
        "nombre_rubro": null, /*TIENE UN VALOR EN LA BD*/
        "descripcion": null
      },
      {
        "id_rubro": 2,
        "nombre_rubro": null, /*TIENE UN VALOR EN LA BD*/
        "descripcion": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Este es el sitio en español, así que todo el contenido debe ir en español, incluido el título. Por favor, ve a [edit] y tradúcelo todo. :)

Comment: Si te trae los otros valores de rubro?

Comment: @gbianchi solo trae el id_rubro, los otros valores no los trae

Comment: Si en la consulta solo seleccionas `rxe.id_rubro` por que crees que te iba a obtener el resto de valores? Intenta añadir en el select el resto de columnas

Answer (score 0):

El problema era el orden de como hacia los joins en la consulta. Asi me anduvo por si alguien tiene un problema similar:

```
[HttpGet("ListarEmpleados/Rubro")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Empleado>>> Get()
        {
            var sql = @"SELECT e.*,r.* FROM Empleado e JOIN RubroXEmpleado rxe ON rxe.id_empleado = e.id_empleado JOIN Rubro r ON  r.id_rubro = rxe.id_rubro";
           
            var empleados = await db.QueryAsync<Empleado, Rubro, Empleado>(sql, (empleado, rubro) =>
            {               
                empleado.rubros.Add(rubro);               
                return empleado;
            }, splitOn: "id_rubro");
            var result = empleados.GroupBy(p => p.id_empleado).Select(g =>
            {
                var groupedPost = g.First();
                groupedPost.rubros = g.Select(p => p.rubros.Single()).ToList();
                return groupedPost;
            });
            
            return result.ToList();


        }
```